# prime faces' paginator doesn't work

Tags: datatable, pagination, primefaces

I work with **prime faces 2.2.1,firefox 4.0**. The code below rendered a datatable with paginator. But the paginator doesn't work. If I delete the code ,it works. But they can't meet my requirement. So how can i work with the paginator without remove the `multiple` attribute?

```
<h:body>        
        <h:form id="dataList">                
                <p:dataTable id="originList" var="doModule" cache="true" lazy="false" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" value="#{allTabManager.applyTab.applyDisplay.moduleList}"  paginatorPosition="bottom" > 
                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
                        <p:column headerText="displayNo" >
                                <h:outputText value="#{doModule.ColIndex.value}" />
                        </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Please edit your question if you have a correction to make. This isn't a forum and answers are meant to be just that: answers. I'd have edited your question for you but as I'm not familiar with Prime Faces, you'd best do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forgotten the selection attribute with p:datatable.

```
<p:dataTable id="originList" var="doModule" cache="true" lazy="false" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" value="#{allTabManager.applyTab.applyDisplay.moduleList}"  paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    selection="#{allTabManager.applyTab.applyDisplay.selections}" >
```

Comment: Hope it won't be deleted again